# One Submenu Open One At a Time & Click to Close

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list with submenus. Now I can open one at a time: Click on List 1 will open submenu 1.  Click on List 2, submenu 2 will open and submenu 1 is closed automatically.

Problem: I click on List 2 again, submenu 2 should be closed based on the `slideToggle()`, but it is closed and open right after that.

Please help.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzyUr/43/)

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li a').on('click', function(){
          $('.square').slideUp();
            $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
    li {padding:20px; border: solid 1px;margin:5px;}
    
    .square {
      display: none;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .active {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li>
            <a class="test">Hover List1</a>
            <div class="square">
            Square 1
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Hover List2</a>
            <div class="square">
            Square 2
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Hover List3</a>
            <div class="square">
            Square 3
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Hover List4</a>
            <div class="square">
            Square 4
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the `slideUp()` for `div` of `parent().siblings()`:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.square').slideUp();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').on('click', function(){
   
         $(this).parent().siblings().find('.square').slideUp();

      
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
li {padding:20px; border: solid 1px;margin:5px;}

.square {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.active {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="test">Hover List1</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List2</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 2
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List3</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 3
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List4</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 4
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```